# What does mean attribute "TRY" in Hunspell

Tags: dictionary, spell-checking, hunspell

Hunspell affix file may contain attribute TRY. What it does?
The Hunspell documentation says:

> Hunspell can suggest right word forms, when they differ from the bad input word by one TRY
>   character. The parameter of TRY is case sensitive.

But I did not understand what it means.
I have following affix and dictionary files:

.aff

```
SET UTF-8
TRY e
```

.dic

```
2
created
create
```

And Hunspell input:

```
create
*

created
*

sreate
& sreate 1 0: create

sreated
& sreated 1 0: created

crzated
& crzated 2 0: created, create
```

You can see, that words "sreate", "sreated", "crzated" differ from the right word forms by "s" and "z" characters. Why this happens?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`TRY` states a set of letters that can be wrong. If a misspelled word differs from a word in the dictionary file by one of these letters, then Hunspell can suggest that dictionary word.

In your example, the letter `e` is mistaken as `z` in `crzated`. Hence Hunspell replaces `z` with `e`.

I'm not sure about `sreate` and `sreated` TBH.

Comment: What is MAXNGRAMSUGS and MAXDIFF doing in this file? https://github.com/Shreeshrii/hindi-hunspell/blob/master/Hindi/hi_IN.aff